# typescript and firebase async await to make multiple calls

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

i am reading few user records from a file line for line. and each line is a user record that i create if it does not exist.  Same user record can be in multiple lines. so basically, if i see it is already created then i just skip.

the code looks like below

```
async onFilesAdded(files: FileList){
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);

    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = async (e) => {
     this.showProgress = true
      var lines = fileReader.result.toString().split(/[\r\n]+/g); // tolerate both Windows and Unix linebreaks
      this.totalLines = lines.length
      var firstLine = false

      this.dcSvc.getPageImages().then(
        (resp) => {
          console.log("resp in getPageImage" + JSON.stringify(resp))
          this.pageMap = resp
          this.lineCount = 0
          for(let line of lines){
            if(firstLine == false){
              firstLine = true
            }else{
               this.createClickHistory(line).then(
                 (resp)=> console.log("line processed")
               )
            }
          }
        }
      )
    }

    fileReader.readAsText(this.fileToUpload);
  }


 async createClickHistory(line:string){
        var lineArr = line.split(',')
        const userName = lineArr[1]

           this.dcSvc.getUser(userName).then(
             (res:any) => {
                         console.log("Response of get user is:::" + JSON.stringify(res))
                         if(res.length == 0 ){
                           //user does not exist in the DB
                           console.log("user:" + userName + " does not exist so creating it")
                           const userPayload = {
                                                 "userName": userName
                                               }

                                               this.dcSvc.createUser(userName, userPayload).then((rsp) => {})

                         }else{
                           //user exists so skip
    }
    }

     createUser(userName:string, userPayload){
        return this.db.object("/users/" + userName).set(userPayload)
      }

      getUser(userName:string){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  this.db.list('/users', 
                      ref => ref.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userName)
                  ).snapshotChanges().subscribe(
                    (res) =>  {
                                resolve(res)
                              }
                  )
                })

      }
```

What I am observing is that the code really does not wait for one line to process. So as a result, i have to run the code multiple times to let the complete data being imported.

Comment: What is your question? And could you please try to intend your code so that it is readable?

Comment: This is not syntactically correct typescript code. Consider posting your real code instead. You can't declare functions without the keyword `function` or by making them arrow functions (`=>`)

Comment: updated code and question. basically the code is not really waiting as i need it to. So my file creates a parent node and then child nodes. The logic aim to first check if a parent node exist. if not then it create it else it just create child to it. but what is happening is that for some reasons it never figures out in first run if the parent is existing. and it keep on overriding.

Comment: Do you have an example of the data file being read?  Not an enormous file, just enough to reproduce the issue you are seeing.

Comment: test data https://www.dropbox.com/s/docnyzrv4eojgj7/testfile.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timeout to delay your line reading:

```
 var t = 0
 for (let line of lines){
   if (firstLine == false){
     firstLine = true
   } else{
     setTimeout(function(line){ this.createClickHistory(line).then(
       (resp)=> console.log("line processed")
     )}.bind(this, line), t*16) // 60fps
   }
   t++
 }
```